# vanilla javascript to use the click of a link but for different command

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```html
<a href="abc.php">Print <span class="asdoc">DoC</span></a>
```

if i click on print, it is navigated, now i am trying to click on the doc to open a popup and download a doc file, can't move the span outside due to the page complexity,

so how i can do with vanilla `javascript`.

any clue, i am sure with `jquery` i can use `stoppropgation` of parent element, but jquery is not an option

Comment: Why tag jQuery if it's not an option? Also `stopPropagation()` is still the correct method to use, you just need to select the `span` to add the event handler to.

Comment: can you show the Javascript part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Event.stopPropagation()`, you can try [**`Event.preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
document.querySelector('.asdoc').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log('You have clicked', e.target);
  console.log('Parent href value is', e.target.parentNode.href);
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<a href="abc.php">Print <span class="asdoc">DoC</span></a>
```

Comment: can i pick the href attribute of a tag also

Comment: @sqler, yes, of course, please check the updated answer:)

Comment: will it have any effect if i am using an iframe, looks like it do, because it does not do the thing what i am asking it to do

Comment: @sqler, the answer I have provided based on the code you have provided in the question (not on what your actual environment is)!